# Password protecting an asp.net site using a log in page

Tags: asp.net, password-protection

I am trying to password protect an asp.net site, i have done this okay, however if they put /home.aspx at the end of the address then it will by pass the log in page, is there a way of making those other pages only accessible through the buttons, and if they are accessed directly it will redirect you to the login page?

THanks

Comment: You need to provide more information. What technique are you using for login? Please show us some example code

Comment: I am currently using a hardcoded password and username, which is okay for the sort of site I am making, what i need to do is stop /home.aspx etc being written at the end of the url to by pass the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you login you should start a session.
This is some code I used in one of my high school projects

```
> public void LoginUser(string id, string mail, string ww, string admin)
>     {
>         Session["UserID"] = id;
>         Session["IsAdmin"] = admin;
>         if(admin == "admin")
>         {
>             Response.Redirect("~/Admin/AdminCP.aspx");
>         }
>         else if (admin == "user")
>         {
>             Response.Redirect("~/User/UserCP.aspx");
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             lblLoginError.Text = "An error has accurred";
>             lblLoginError.Visible = true;
>             lblLoginError.CssClass = "failureNotification left";
>         }
>     }
```

This is a way I used detecting if a user was an admin or a basic user.
After this, in every page in the Page_Load-section you have to add

```
> if (Session["UserID"] == null)
>         {
>             Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login.aspx");
>         }
```

This will check everytime if the session UserID is running. If it is empty, the login never happened, so the user will be redirected to the page where he can login.

Hope this helped ;-)

Answer (score 0):

unless you are using some other way.. just checkout the asp.net membership provider documentation on msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx

if you scroll right to the bottom this is what you are looking for, but this page gives all the info you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the log on state in session and check on page load or pre init for an isLoggedin flag which only gets set if they have logged in successfully. This won't prevent them navigating directly to pages if they are logged in but will keep them out if they aren't.

Comment: Could you give me some example code for this? When logged in the users can see all pages, so what you are saying would be ideal

Comment: To your log on script just add something like
Session["LoggedIn"] = "true"
and to the page load or onInit just put in

if (Session["LoggedIn"] == null || Session["LoggedIn"].ToString() != "true")
{
response.redirect // to login page
}