# Protecting a aspx page with username and password

Tags: asp.net

I have a Default.aspx page that i need to protect with a username and password, and i have been searching via Google on a simple Login.aspx page where it protects the Default.aspx page without luck, as i'm not a .net developer.

Do you have any examples for me, a very basic code to protect the Default.aspx page with a username and Password ?.

Thanks in Advance, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Look on the right in the related questions. This is the first one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296538/password-protecting-an-asp-net-site-using-a-log-in-page?rq=1

Comment: you will have to learn things before using it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you the best way i know..[Form Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)

You should first read this to understand [what form authentication is and how it works](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98950/ASP-NET-authentication-and-authorization), then look at this [example](http://bradkingsley.com/securing-asp-net-pages-forms-authentication-c-and-net-4/) for your help.

Comment: Isn't there any copy/paste solution ?, i'm having a hard time understanding those examples ?...

Comment: strange looking for copy/paste solution?